# Why can't chlorine atoms form hydrogen bonds?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, electronegativity, hydrogen-bond

Why can't chlorine atoms form hydrogen bonds even though they have very similar electronegativity to nitrogen, which can?

Electronegativities are as follows:

$\ce{Cl} - 3.16$

$\ce{N} - 3.04$

Is it because of the size ?

Comment: The existence of hydrogen bonds involving chlorine atoms was disputed a while ago, but experimental data show that chlorine atoms can form hydrogen bonds, and are in fact very common. See C.B. Aakeröy et al., The C–H···Cl hydrogen bond: does it exist?  New J. Chem., 1999,23, 145-152. DOI: 10.1039/A809309A

Comment: I really hate to do that, but quora actually has **a** good answer on that. (**a** as in one, only one good answer, i.e. the one by by Mario Barbatti) [find it here](https://www.quora.com/Why-can-chlorine-atoms-not-form-hydrogen-bonds-even-though-they-have-very-similar-electronegativity-to-nitrogen-which-can)

Comment: also related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/5503/4945

Comment: and here is real answer http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21773/why-is-hydrogen-bonding-generally-defined-to-include-only-three-period-two-eleme

Comment: If I wanted to close, I'd rather close as the latter. @Mith Anyway, I will let you guys decide...

Comment: Yeah, probably second one is better.

Comment: This discussion is really dubious. I would be careful about saying that chlorine engages in hydrogen bonds and argue with e.g. Cl-H-Br hydrogen bonds. Hydrogen bonds are mainly interesting in a biological context and then there are no chlorine hydrogen bonds. Even if there are chlorine bromine hydrogen bonds when you stir fuming HCl in a magic acid mixture at 400°C this doesn't mean that they occur in real world scenarios as well. Show me one protein where a Cl h.-bond occurs and I am convinced. $\mathrm{Cl^-}$ is just not basic enough to engage in significantly strong hydrogen bonds. Period.

Comment: @ketbra Seems you're not accepting the existance of weak H-bonds. All this N,O,F stuff are moderately or very strong examples but there can be weak or even very weak ones and they are also important, for example in protein folding.

Comment: @Mithoron Than could you please give an example where Cl is important in protein folding?

Comment: General stuff about weak H-bonds: http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2000/CC/A900221I Halogens in hydrogen bonds: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/cg015522k#page=8&zoom=auto,-99,758